# How do I use let in node in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code that I've tried to use is shown below. How do I make this work with `pdflatex`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]

  \foreach \y in {0, 1, 2}{
    \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2}{
      \path
        let
          \n1 = {\x+random(2)},
          \n2 = {\y+random(2)}
        in
          node at (\n1,\n2) [shape=circle,draw] {$p_{\x,\y}$};
    }
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal document, not just fragments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're bitten by the fact that inside a `let` block `\x` and `\y` can have a special meaning. E.g., if you say `\p1=(3,2)`, then `\x1` is 3 and `\y1` is 2. I know you don't do that, but I think the definition of `\x` and `\y` change after `let`.

If you change them to `\X` and `\Y` your code works. But note that you don't actually need it here I think, you can do calculations directly in a coordinate specification, so you can say `\node at ({\x+random(2)},{\y+random(2)}) ...`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \y in {0, 1, 2}{
  \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2}{      
    \node at ({\x+random(2)},{\y+random(2)}) [shape=circle,draw] {$p_{\x,\y}$};
  }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Y in {0, 1, 2}{
  \foreach \X in {0, 1, 2}{      
    \path
      let 
        \n1 = {\X+random(2)},
        \n2 = {\Y+random(2)}
      in     
        node at (\n1,\n2) [shape=circle,draw] {$p_{\X,\Y}$};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect! Tanks a lot!